# Is this registry string inconsequential?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, gaming

So I just finished upgrading a dozen hard drives, went through the process of migrating all the data, and was just about to finish up when something unrelated drew my attention to this portion of the registry:

```
HKCU\System\GameConfigStore\Children\randomgameid\UtmItemId
```

I noticed that many of these keys had no such string [`UtmItemId`], however the ones that did, referenced an old location [`W~G:\Dragon Age - Origins\bin_ship\DAOrigins.exe`], which was at one time on `G:`, two drives ago;  It seemingly skipped the drive I just migrated from [`I:`] and is now at `S:\Standard\Dragon Age - Origins\bin_ship\DAOrigins.exe`, which is properly shown by the `MatchedExeFullPath` string.

I have no idea what the `UtmItemId` string is, much less what `W~` signifies, other than the fact it's pointing to a very old location.  I'm not sure if this is tethered elsewhere, or if its some kind of "look here if it's not in xx location" type thing or even deprecated since it didn't update to the intermediary path.

I want to clean these out, but don't want to break anything in the process; Can anyone enlighten me on their function and the safety of their removal?

Comment: That string is not on any computers here of mine, so it must have been added from somewhere.

Comment: Why not just ignore it? If you delete, export the key first, that way it can be restored if it gives trouble. Looks like a game from the app store.

Comment: Unless there's an actual reason for removing keys from the Registry, leave it be... the Registry does not need to be cleaned, contrary to what many 3rd party applications would have users believe.  If for whatever reason you do want to remove keys due to a shoddy uninstaller not cleaning up after it's installer, use [RegEditX](https://www.dcsoft.com/products/regeditx/)'s RegCrawler feature, which makes searching and replacing keys en masse far more convenient _(back up `%WinDir%\System32\config` and `%UserProfile%\NTUSER.DAT` files before modifying)_

Comment: CCleaner does that too. Usually with not too many issues to deal with afterwards. And the free version remains free forever...

Comment: yea ive used ccleaner for years with 0 issues that i know of anyways.

as for the reasoning behind deletion, the subkeys are tied to windows FSO functionality which has given me a lot of trouble.   Years ago i modified some strings in there to all-hell so to speak.   It served its purpose at the time, but im trying to return things to default which seems to be without those keys.

Ive done a search for that subkeys guid, and the value (path) in the string that points to the old drive.  They both ONLY return that location.

Is this make it reasonable to assume safety?